# Cascade deletion is not working in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

i have 2 models

```
var Professional = sequelize.define('professional', {
name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: true
},
associate: function (models) {
    Professional.belongsTo(models.User,
        {
          foreignKey: {allowNull: false},
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
}}
```

and

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  unique: true
},
associate: function (models) {
    User.hasOne(models.Professional,
        {
          foreignKey: {allowNull: true},
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
}}
```

But when i Delete a Professional corresponding user not get deleted.

When i checked in the `postgres` constraint looks like

`TABLE "professional" CONSTRAINT "professional_userId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES "user"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`

Can anyone explain this behaviour...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't delete row in `user` table through deleting row in `professional`, so `user` table is main and `professional` is secondary(with foreign key userId). But you can delete professional's row through deleting user's row.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.